# rlang - get the class of an object passed as a string, rather than the string itself or the quo

Tags: r, rlang

I'm trying to get the classes of columns in a tibble by passing a string of the column name.  As usual the documentation for rlang is so indecipherable that I can't figure out how to make the string be evaluated as the actual object, and attempts I've made return the class of "quosure" or "name".

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rlang))

(colstable <- mtcars %>% names %>% enframe(name = NULL, value = "column"))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 1
#>    column
#>    <chr> 
#>  1 mpg   
#>  2 cyl   
#>  3 disp  
#>  4 hp    
#>  5 drat  
#>  6 wt    
#>  7 qsec  
#>  8 vs    
#>  9 am    
#> 10 gear  
#> 11 carb


colstable %>% 
  mutate(colclass = class(sym(paste0("mtcars$", column))))
#> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols


#This crashes Rstudio immediately:
#colstable %>% 
  #mutate(colclass = class(quo(paste0("mtcars$", column))))

class(sym("mtcars$mpg"))
#> [1] "name"

class(quo("mtcars$mpg"))
#> [1] "quosure" "formula"

#Desired output would be the classes as produced by str()
str(mtcars)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

#Ie, all the values of "colclass" should be "num"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurred because `sym` works only on a single element.  Here, we need `syms` (but it is not the route to get the expected output).  The `$` with variable name will evaluate it literally, so instead use `[[`

If we need the `class`, then just do

```
library(dplyr)
colstable %>%
      rowwise %>% 
      mutate(colclass = class(mtcars[[column]]) )
# A tibble: 11 x 2
# Rowwise: 
#   column colclass
#   <chr>  <chr>   
# 1 mpg    numeric 
# 2 cyl    numeric 
# 3 disp   numeric 
# 4 hp     numeric 
# 5 drat   numeric 
# 6 wt     numeric 
# 7 qsec   numeric 
# 8 vs     numeric 
# 9 am     numeric 
#10 gear   numeric 
#11 carb   numeric
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
colstable %>%
     mutate(colclass = map_chr(column ~ class(mtcars[[.x]])))
```

---

Or if we need to `eval`uate the expression

```
library(stringr)
colstable %>%
    mutate(colclass = map_chr(rlang::parse_exprs(str_c("mtcars$", column, collapse=";")),
         ~ class(rlang::eval_tidy(.x))))
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   column colclass
#   <chr>  <chr>   
# 1 mpg    numeric 
# 2 cyl    numeric 
# 3 disp   numeric 
# 4 hp     numeric 
# 5 drat   numeric 
# 6 wt     numeric 
# 7 qsec   numeric 
# 8 vs     numeric 
# 9 am     numeric 
#10 gear   numeric 
#11 carb   numeric
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, except that when I have an ordered factor (where `class()` returns a vector length 2), it immediately crashes R.

require(tidyverse)

colstable <- diamonds %>% 
  names %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL, value = "column")

colstable %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(colclass = class(diamonds[[column]]))

Comment: @jzadra in that case, you can change the code to return the first one, i.e. `colstable %>%
    mutate(colclass = map_chr(rlang::parse_exprs(str_c("mtcars$", column, collapse=";")),
         ~ class(rlang::eval_tidy(.x))[1]))`

Comment: @jzadra or instead of `map_chr`, use just `map`, so that it returns a `list`

Comment: it's odd that this wouldn't work given that the result is character rather than vector:

colstable %>% 
  filter(!(column %in% c("cut", "color", "clarity"))) %>% #removed ordered factors
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(colclass = class(diamonds[[column]]))

Comment: This works and it doesn't require `map`.  Odd that collapsing doesn't.

colstable %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(colclass = class(diamonds[[column]])[1])

Comment: @jzadra if you do `rowwise`, it doesn't need `map`

Comment: @jzadra i meant `colstable %>% mutate(colclass = map_chr(column, ~ class(diamonds[[.x]])[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

Don't really see a need of `rlang` or any non-standard evaluation here.

We can get class of columns using `map` and get data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(mtcars, class) %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything())

#  column class  
#   <chr>  <chr>  
# 1 mpg    numeric
# 2 cyl    numeric
# 3 disp   numeric
# 4 hp     numeric
# 5 drat   numeric
# 6 wt     numeric
# 7 qsec   numeric
# 8 vs     numeric
# 9 am     numeric
#10 gear   numeric
#11 carb   numeric
```

If there are only specific columns that we are interested in we can `select` them before getting their `class`.

---

If you have to use `colstable` we can `pull` the column from the dataframe and get its class.

```
colstable %>% mutate(class = map_chr(column, ~mtcars %>% pull(.x) %>% class))
```